# How to fetch data from core data and display in table View iOS 6

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data

I have successfully stored address book data in Core Data but i m not able to retrieve it and display it in tableView .What am i missing ?

This is how i fetch data from core data.

```
-(void)fetchFromDatabase
{
  AddressBookAppDelegate *appDelegate =[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
  NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];
  NSEntityDescription *entityDesc = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"AddressBook" inManagedObjectContext:context];
  NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
  [request setEntity:entityDesc];

  NSError *error;
  self.arrayForTable = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
   NSLog(@"fetched data = %@",[self.arrayForTable lastObject]); //this shows the data
   [self.tableView reloadData];
```

And this is my table view configuration.

```
 - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
   return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
  return [self.arrayForTable count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
   if (cell == nil) {
   cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
   reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

   if ([self.arrayForTable count]>0)
   {
       NSLog(@" table view content  = %@",[self.arrayForTable lastObject]);// this doesn't log
       AddressBook *info = [self.arrayForTable objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
       cell.textLabel.text = info.firstName;

    }
    }
  return cell;
}
```

Comment: Try adding `[self.tableView reloadData]` at the end of your `fetchFromDatabase` method. - You should also consider to use a NSFetchedResultsController to display Core Data objects in a table view.

Comment: I updated the [self.tableView reloadData]; method . but the result is same.

Comment: Are `numberOfRowsInSection` and `cellForRowAtIndexPath` called at all?

Comment: numberOfRowsInSection is called but cellForRowAtIndexPath doesn't get called.

Comment: What is the value of `[self.arrayForTable count]` in `numberOfRowsInSection`?

Comment: No I don't think that is called too.Since i tried this int n = [self.arrayForTable count];
 NSLog(@"array count = %d",n); And it doesn't log anything.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36612/discussion-between-martin-r-and-sushrut)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turned out in the discussion, `self.arrayForTable` was replaced by an empty array in `viewWillAppear` *after* fetching the objects in `fetchFromDatabase`.

Another problem was that each run of the program created new objects in the database,
leading to duplicate objects. You can either

- delete all objects before inserting the new objects, or
- for each name, check if a matching object already exists in the database, and insert a new one only if necessary.

More advanced techniques are described in ["Implementing Find-or-Create Efficiently"](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdImporting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003174-SW4) in the "Core Data Programming Guide".